# Proper way to iterate over a set while keeping track of index

Tags: java

I want to essentially map a set to an array after calling someMethod on each element. Should I loop through using a foreach loop and a "i" variable outside, or use a regular for loop and iterator?

```
int[] arr = new int[set.size()];
int i = 0;
for(int ele : set) {
  arr[i] = someMethod(ele);
  i++;
}
```

or

```
int[] arr = new int[set.size()];
Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
for(int i=0; i<set.size(); i++) {
  arr[i] = someMethod(iterator.next().intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are equally good but for loop is slightly faster than forEach loop,

There are some other methods to convert set to array given below.
You can use `toArray()` function :

```
    int[] arr = new int[set.size()];
    arr = set.toArray(arr);
```

or you can use stream in java 8 or above:

```
  int[] arr = set.stream().toArray(int[] ::new);
```

Another method is by using  `Arrays.copyOf`

```
int[] arr = Arrays.copyOf(set.toArray(), set.size(), Integer[].class);
```

Comment: While a for loop is slightly faster than an *equivalent* for each loop, this for loop is not equivalent to a simple for each loop.  If you look carefully, the for loop version is both incrementing a variable and iterating an iterator.  This is slower than both a simple `for` and a simple for each.

Comment: but this is not what OP looks for: `after calling someMethod on each element`.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are correct in the sense that they both give the same result.

However, in my opinion the first version is the preferable of the two.

- It is easier to understand for an average Java programmer.
- It is more concise.  Fewer lines of code.  Simpler statements.
- It will probably be faster ... unless the optimizer is amazingly clever.

---

If it was me, I would save a line and write it like this:

```
for(int ele : set) {
  arr[i++] = someMethod(ele);
}
```

but that is just my old C habits shining through.

---

As others have pointed out, in Java 8+ there is an even more concise way to write this; e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68707947/139985).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Both of your loops are equivalent.

You can use streams to make a one-liner, where the stream does the looping for you.

```java
int[] arrayOfInts =
        Set
                .of( 1 , 2 , 3 )
                .stream()
                .mapToInt( Integer :: intValue )
                .map( integer -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , integer ) )
                .sorted()
                .toArray();
```

> arrayOfInts = [1, 4, 9]

## Either loop is good

Both of your loops work well.

Choose whichever is easiest to read and understand. For me that would usually be the for-each syntax, as seen in your first loop.

By the way, that first loop could be shortened. The `i++` syntax pulls out and utilizes the value of `i` *before* incrementing. So you can nest the `i++` inside your array index accessor.

```java
Set < Integer > set = Set.of( 1 , 2 , 3 );
int[] arr = new int[ set.size() ];
int i = 0;
for ( int element : set ) {
    arr[ i++ ] = Math.multiplyExact( element , element );  // Auto-boxing converts `Integer` objects into `int` primitive values.
}

System.out.println( "arr = " + Arrays.toString( arr ) );
```

> arr = [1, 9, 4]

## Stream instead of loop

The [Answer by Pranav Choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68707947/642706) is correct. But you also mentioned wanting to apply a method to modify your number before assigning to the array.

Java streams make it easy to perform such a modification during collection.

Define our `Set` of `Integer` objects.

```
Set < Integer > set = Set.of( 1 , 2 , 3 );
```

Create a stream of `int` primitives, boxed from our `Integer` objects.

```
IntStream intStream = set.stream().mapToInt( Integer :: intValue );
```

Apply your modification. Here we square each number. The [`Math.multiplyExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(int,int)) method is handy because it will throw an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) if we overflow the limits of the [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) `int` type. We collect each resulting square as an `int` in our array.

```
int[] arrayOfInts = intStream.map( integer -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , integer ) ).toArray();
```

Dump to console.

System.out.println( "arrayOfInts = " + Arrays.toString( arrayOfInts ) );

When run.

> arrayOfInts = [9, 4, 1]

Notice the order of the output. A `Set` by definition has no determined iteration order. To emphasize that, the [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E,E)) method reserves the right to use an implementation of `Set` that randomly changes its iteration. So each time you run this code you may see a different ordering of results.

If you care about order, add that to your stream work. Add a call to [`sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sorted()).

```
int[] arrayOfInts = intStream.map( integer -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , integer ) ).sorted().toArray();
```

When run, we get consistent ordering. See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/C9bwWK).

> arrayOfInts = [1, 4, 9]

Not that I recommend it, but we could turn this code into a one-liner.

```
int[] arrayOfInts = Set.of( 1 , 2 , 3 ).stream().mapToInt( Integer :: intValue ).map( integer -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , integer ) ).sorted().toArray();
```

Or:

```java
int[] arrayOfInts =
        Set
                .of( 1 , 2 , 3 )
                .stream()
                .mapToInt( Integer :: intValue )
                .map( integer -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , integer ) )
                .sorted()
                .toArray();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pnp8qw).

> arrayOfInts = [1, 4, 9]

Answer (score 0):

With java8:

```
    Integer[] arr = set.stream().map(element -> doSomething(element)).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Where `doSomething()` is your method which you can call -

> calling someMethod on each element.